# How to export table in php?

Tags: php, database, export

I am new to php and want to export tables from databse to excell datasheet how do i achieve this please explain in simple language as i am very new to php. Please explain this to me with suitable example. 
Thank You

Comment: See, there is already help posted, check this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131743/creating-excel-file-from-mysql-using-php

Comment: Have you googled for _export mysql to excel_ ?
Do you use phpMyAdmin because you can just hit _export_ there. If you want to programe regular exports or without phpMyAdmin, this is not a task for someone very new. You could also use CURL to GET the phpMyAdmin pages for export.

Comment: visit site http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: Aside from generating csv or html, have you looked at any of the libraries like those listed in the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel

Comment: @DanFromGermany he is not clear if he want data from database directly or using php he want to export from client side.

Answer (score 2):

You require to create new style sheet print.css and set CSS media=print

for example :

```
<style media="screen">
  .noPrint{ display: block; }
  .yesPrint{ display: block !important; }
</style>

<style media="print">
  .noPrint{ display: none; }
  .yesPrint{ display: block !important; }
</style>
```

and add class to "yesPrint" to the sections you want to print

```
<div class= "yesPrint">
 <table border="1">
 <tr>
 <th>Header 1</th>
 <th>Header 2</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
 <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
 <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
```

Now add a button

```
<input TYPE="button" onClick="window.print()">
```

for more detatil : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/Printing_with_CSS.aspx

**Or** Use [TableTools](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/#).It is a plug-in for the DataTables HTML table enhancer, which adds a highly customisable button toolbar to a DataTable. Key features include:

- Copy to clipboard
- Save table data as CSV, XLS or PDF files
- Print view for clean printing
- Row selection options
- Easy use predefined buttons
- Simple customisation of buttons
- Well defined API for advanced control